# Does Windows Phone 7 have a standard Edit/Add/Delete convention?

Tags: iphone, windows-phone-7, user-interface, windows-phone-7.1

On the iPhone, there is a standard convention for editing [lists](http://www.pennpoints.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/iPhone-alarm-screen-e1294194258534.png).  You have the list, above that there is the `Edit` button and the `+` button.  You click on the `Edit` button and the list changes slightly notifying the user of change of status.

Does Windows Phone 7 have some type of a standard convention for editing lists?  It seems every app implements their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are UI design guidelines published and maintained by Microsoft for Windows Phone development:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=220811

I'm not sure it will mention "standards" per se.  However, the Phone's built in applications (Hotmail, People, etc), all tend towards a common way and a podcast from Metro designers on Silverlight TV advised to behave similarly to the provided apps.

What I've tended to notice is:

- Add button above the list or on the app bar.
- Edit button inside the item itself on the app bar.
- Delete button on the app bar with checkboxes (Hotmail), or delete by holding down to get a context menu.

Answer (score 2):

In the `August Silverlight Toolkit`, there's a control which mimicks the way emails/etc. are deleted on the device:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550

Comment: Can you point me to an example of this control?  I don't see any.

Comment: @AngryHacker: it's called the `multiselectlist` on the toolkit sample.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think not. There are some general guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) on the subject, but nothing concrete. It boils down to "Be consistent, but unique".

The latest [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) (requires Mango) has a control for doing this similar to how the rest of the phone does it - but there is nothing stopping you for doing it your own way if that's what you prefer.