# Does Android have a standard Add/Edit/Delete list convention?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, standards

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475407/does-windows-phone-7-have-a-standard-edit-add-delete-convention),  but this one is about Android.

On the iPhone, there is a standard convention for editing lists. There is an Edit button and the + button above the list. You click on the Edit button and the list changes slightly notifying the user of change of status.

I have a dozen apps on Android that manage lists in some way and they all seem to do it slightly differently.  Does Android have some type of a standard convention for editing lists?   Perhaps something that's recommended by the Android team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there is no such standard exist but for that you have create custom title bar with Edit/Post options same as [Wordpress for Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.wordpress.android) application, you can also download this code of wordpress application because its open source application. So if you download this code, then it may be helpful to you to understand the Edit functionality for the listview.

[image]

Update:
In short, i just want to say that you have to define custom and efficient adapter for ListView.